# Indenting Issue after ?> in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: tags, pydev

The formatting is giving me issue in Aptana studio 3, this is what I want.

```
<?php
if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        if (condition) {
            if (condition) {
            } else {
                if (condition) {                    
                    ?>
                        <!--a block of html code would go here
                        a block of html code would go here
                        a block of html code would go here
                        a block of html code would go here
                        a block of html code would go here
                        -->                 
                    <?php

                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
}
?>
```

However after formatting this is what I get:

```
<?php
if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        if (condition) {
            if (condition) {
            } else {
                if (condition) {                    

?>
<!--a block of html code would go here
a block of html code would go here
a block of html code would go here
a block of html code would go here
a block of html code would go here
-->
<?php
}
}
}
}
} else {
}
?>
```

It looks like the formatter is having problems with me coming out of php to enter html, however I do not want to use echo as the html is a lot.

Netbeans deals with this fine.
How do I fix this in Aptana Studio?

Thanks